# Metasploitable server

Tags: command-line, permissions, virtualbox

I'm not sure if this would be the right place to ask this question.

I've created a sample website using metaexploitable OS, and since this is a terminal-based OS I've been having trouble coding my html site with the vi editor, I was wondering if anyone know how to can access my root directory (and have control, adding files into the root directory) for a different machine.

Right now I'm running metaexploit on VirtualBox and I'm able to access the root directory and the files from my host machine (Windows 10)

All my files for the server are located in the directory `/var/www`, and when I do `http://server_ip_addr`, I get to the directory folder which states index on it, I see a few files that I've created etc.

I've also noticed that there is a myPHPAdmin file which when I went to that section of the site, `http://my_ip_addr:80/myPHPAdmin`

I required a username and password. Would I need access to this in order to be able to upload files into my server directory? If so does anyone know the default username and password? I did some research and from my understanding (might be completely off) that I would need to install a database in order to even log into that section.

So if anyone has any ideas on what I can do in order to load files into that directory using my host machine, or if there is no means to do that, if anyone could recommend a good text editor where editing isn't such a drag, I would greatly appreciate it!

I'm running Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 Server

Thank you!

Comment: I assume that you're using Metasploitable 3. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHPMyAdmin login credentials should be these:

- User: `root`
- Password: (leave it blank)

Source: [Metasploitable 3 Wiki - Vulnerabilities](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploitable3/wiki/Vulnerabilities)

---

You should not need to install anything (less yet "a database [server]") to access the system.

---

If you have a relative lack of experience using `vi`, I would recommend you `nano`, which is a bit more friendly.